# How to pass curl request

Tags: java, android, web-services, curl

How can i pass this request in Android app?

```
curl -X POST -F "images_file=@fruitbowl.jpg" "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify?api_key={api-key}&version=2016-05-20"
```

Answer (score 0):

refer bellow links for curl -X POST -F

http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAB/Developers/GettingStarted/API%20requests/curl-formats.htm

https://edoceo.com/cli/curl